# Code behind does not run from HTML with <% tags

Tags: html, vb.net

I have the following HTML:

```
<td align="center">
        <%#CreateDynamicHTML()%>
```

The <%# %> tags, whatever they're called, are meant to point to a code behind function. Here is my function:

```
Public Function CreateDynamicHTML() As String
    Dim html As String = String.Empty
    'create lots of HTML

    Return html
End Function
```

It compiles but the function does not run. Put a break point in there, doesn't get hit. What's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The # symbol is for databinding. The = symbol is short for Response.Write. Try using <%=CreateDynamicHTML()%>.

Comment: You're a genius! Thanks. I can't give you a like on the number thingy on the left because I have to have 15 reputation whatever that means. But thanks anyway.